# iPhone push notification server : something to do after server changed?

Tags: php, iphone, push-notification

I successfully manage to implement an iPhone push notification server (PHP) last year; I had to change the server, and was thinking that moving files was sufficient... I was wrong, since the modification notifications are not sent anymore. There's no error, everything seems ok, but notification aren't received.

Below is my server code; anyone can think of a cause, or a way to find the problem ? (notes: the $deviceTokens var is correct, contains the device tokens, and I've successfully tested my .pem certificate with an openssl command).

```
    $payload['aps'] = array('alert' => 'notification!!', 'sound' => 'push.aif');
    $payload = json_encode($payload);

    $streamContext = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'libraries/ck_prod.pem');
    $apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:' . 2195, $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

    if($error) {
        log_message('error', $errorString);
        return;
    }

    log_message('debug', 'sending push notification...');

    if($apns) {
        foreach($deviceTokens as $deviceToken) {
            $apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
            fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);
        }
        fclose($apns);
    } else {
        log_message('error', 'error while sending push notification');
    }
```

Comment: I am having the same prob I am neither getting error nor push notifications are received, I receive push notification if I use the files on other server, but if I use on my server I don't receive notifications. How did you solve the prob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well well... Maybe I should have notice that I was contacting the test server (gateway.**sandbox**.push.apple.com)... Some days are just difficult...